# MySQL Connection Error: Value Preferred is not of the correct type mysql

Tags: c#, mysql, macos, ubuntu, .net-core

I am working on .NET Core project with MySQL on an Ubuntu Server. I am using Visual Studio on a Mac. The NuGet package I installed is MySql.Data 8.0.8-dmr, it's not a stable version (maybe that's just the point, but let me go on).

I have no SSL certificates on that machine, it's just in the local network for development purposes.

I am using a connection string that looks like this:
Server=[Ip address to that server]; Port=3306; Database=MyDatabase; Uid=MyUser; Pwd=MyPassword; SslMode=Preferred;

When I connect with MySQL Workbench with SSL Mode configured to "if available", the connection works fine. When I try to do this connection with my code, an exception of the type System.ArgumentException is thrown:

```
Value 'Preferred' is not of the correct type.
```

If I change SslMode to "None" in the connection string, my code can connect to the MySQL server.

I do not understand, why it does not work with the "Preferred" value. Shouldn't it be the fallback option anyway, when I say "Preferred"?

The MySQL server has this version: 5.7.18-0ubuntu0.16.04.1.

Answer (score 0):

Check this link [MySQL connection strings](https://www.connectionstrings.com/mysql/). You need to have the ***Connector/.Net*** package which I think you don't. Also you need at least version 6.2.1.

Also, here is the [Deployment guide](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-net/en/) on how to deploy it on an Ubuntu Server.!

[image]

On another note from [this link](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-net/en/connector-net-connection-options.html), the default value for SslMode is '**Preferred**', so I would think there are no problems there.